# Scrapy:Pass data between 2 spiders

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to create a spider that crawls for some data from web site.
part of the data is an external URL.

I already created the spider that crawls the data from the root site and now i want to write the spider for external web pages.

I was thinking of creating a crawlspider that uses the SgmlLinkExtractor to follow some specific links in each external web page.

what is the recommended way to communicate the list of start_url to the second spider?

My idea is to generate a json file for the items and to read the attribute in start_requests of the second spider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already created the spider that crawls the data from the root site
>   and now i want to write the spider for external web pages.

Save these external page urls to a db.

> what is the recommended way to communicate the list of start_url to the second spider?

Override [`BaseSpider.start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) in your other spider and create requests from urls you get from the db.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I did.
I saved the urls to a file and the second spider reads and parse it all in start_requests.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague but here is one way (??)

```
class PracticeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project_name"
    allowed_domains = ["my_domain.org"]

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = "The First Page URL"
        return [Request(start_urls, callback=self.parse)]

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse the first page
        yield self.pageParser(response)

        # grab the external URLs you want to follow
        ext_urls = ...

        for url in ext_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.pageParser)

    def pageParser(self, response):
        # parse the page
        return items
```

There is also a **meta={}** attribute in Request that might be of some help.